Deploy website via Azure DevOps pipeline using Publish Profile
I have a website built with NET7/8 and Blazor that I deploy from Visual Studio to the server provider using the Web Publish Profile that the provider provides.

The Web Publish Profile is like that
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>http://example.com</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>f723c835-b603-4dc7-9b00-c1845be8fa20</ProjectGuid>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>
        https://example.com:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=example.com
    </MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>example.com</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>true</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>true</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <EnableMsDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMsDeployAppOffline>
    <UserName>forumpur</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>true</_SavePWD>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>browser-wasm</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

I'm trying to create a YAML in the Azure DevOps for a pipeline to deploy from Azure DevOps the website automatically.
I saw in the creation of the pipeline, there is a task called MSDeploy Package Sync but it doesn't have all the parameters I think I need.
Do you have any recommendations on how I can create the pipeline using the Publish Profile?


You can try to use the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task to run the 'dotnet publish' command in your pipeline to deploy the website to the IIS server:

If the IIS server cannot be accessible from Internet (public networks), you need to set up a self-hosted agent on your own local machine (or VM) that can access the IIS server.

Configure the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task in the pipeline runs on the self-hosted agent.
jobs:
- job: publish
  pool: 
    name: {name of the agent pool}
    demands: Agent.Name -equals {name of the agent}
  steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish webside'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '-p:PublishProfile={name of Publish Profile}'




EDIT:
If the server can be accessible from public networks, sure, you do not have to use the self-hosted agent, you can also use Microsoft-hosted agents to run the pipeline.
In the YAML pipeline, if you do not explicitly specify an agent using the pool key, the pipeline will use the Microsoft-hosted agent ubuntu-latest by default, it will be equivalent to the configuration below.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

If you want to use a different agent, you need to use the pool key to explicitly specify that agent or the agent pool. For example.
# Use the Microsoft-hosted agent 'windows-latest'

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest


EDIT_2:
If you wants to use the existing .pubxml.user file, you need to push this file tother with other project code files into Azure Repos (source control). However, since the .pubxml.user file is storing the sensitive information (like the publish password), you should not push it into any source control. Instead, you can try to run the 'dotnet publish' command like as below.
dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile=<PublishProfile> -p:Password=<PublishPassword>


Use the property "-p:PublishProfile=<PublishProfile>" to pass the publish profile to the command.
Use the property "-p:Password=<PublishPassword>" to pass the publish password to the command.

In the pipeline, you can set the value of publish password as a secret variable, and then use this secret variable on the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task.

jobs:
- job: publish
  steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish webside'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '-p:PublishProfile=<PublishProfile> -p:Password=$(publish_pwd)'



Where do I have to save the Publish Profile? The account has a password. How can I pass it?

The server is public. Do I have to add the pool?

@Enrico, I have updated my above answer with more information (see EDIT). Check and try it.

Thank you for your answer. The server is provided by a server provider that gives me only the Web Deploy Publishing service and with it I can deploy from Visual Studio. I can't install anything on the machine. Using Visual Studio, I have 2 files: Web Deploy.pubxml and Web Deploy.pubxml.user.. Can I use those files in the pipeline to deploy to the public server?

@Enrico, See EDIT_2 for more information in my answer.

@Enrico, No problem. Go ahead please. Any update, you can comment here.
